# Map marker setIcon called very fast creates an issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

If a marker is set with icon1 and I then call setIcon twice in a row with icon2 and icon1 again, the marker ends up being displayed with icon2.

```
marker.setIcon(icon1);

// Then later on:

marker.setIcon(icon2);
marker.setIcon(icon1);

// marker is displayed with icon2
```

My explanation is that icon2 has not been loaded from the server yet and the marker is updated with it asynchronously when the image is finished loading.

Apart from preloading all my icons first (which would be tedious in my project because many icons have dynamic names that depend on the content of data on the map), is there a way to handle this on the google maps js api side?

**Update**: [here is the code to reproduce it](https://jsfiddle.net/dp65fgjn/1/).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to toggle it with `marker.setVisible()`. 
Some strangeness with gmaps I have solved by calling functions with `setTimeout`, but that is just another workaround.

Comment: Thanks, but no it does not work. Each marker is already visible initially anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems to be making a race condition with changing markers as it is an async process,I'd recommend using the data layer instead and use the dynamic styling to set the marker based on a data attribute.

```js
function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4375, 12.3358);
  const myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
  const point = {
    geometry: myLatLng,
    id: 1,
    properties: {
      warn: false
    }
  };
  dl = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
  console.log("Adding feature:");
  console.log(point);
  dl.setStyle(setStyle);
  dl.add(point);
  dl.addListener('mouseover', e => {
   e.feature.setProperty("warn", true);
  });
  dl.addListener('mouseout', e => {
   e.feature.setProperty("warn", false);
  });
}

function setStyle(feature) {
 console.log('setting style for feature');
 const warn = feature.getProperty('warn');
  let icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png';
 if (warn) {
   icon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/caution.png';
  }
  const style = {
   title: feature.getId(),
   icon: icon
  };
  console.log("style = " + style);
  return style;
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAj0aaMu_aY6xiDSWH0ac_4pqN_l-opwmI&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: I have changed my code to use a data layer. Although it is a clean way to make my code better, it does not change anything to the original issue. An icon still overrides another if it takes time to load! And I can easily make it work or fail by enabling or disabling the browser cache. With cache, load is so fast that the problem won't happen. Disable the cache and you can see the issue again.

Comment: Also note that I'm even able to reproduce the issue with your own example. Disable the cache in the console and move your mouse very fast over the marker. The caution icon will stay instead of reverting back to the pin.

Comment: Yes, this is surely noted, in addition to this, this is why we recommend to use data layer to preload all the icons first instead of calling it asynchronously :)

Comment: Your sample does not show how to preload icons in a data layer. Could you please explain that? My icons are numerous and are dynamically generated by my server. When the browser calls server.com/marker/45, it generates an image with '45' in a bubble to show that there are 45 items there...

Comment: Please, can you advise how to preload icons? Is it specific to data layer?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, enabling the cache will do the trick, If the cache is enabled, you will not need to reload the icon again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but as I understand, data layer is not a solution compared to markers and relying on the browser cache sounds more like a workaround that does not fix the first visit to the page.